Error new create a new record --AttributeError: '_unknown' object has no attribute 'id'-- how to solve it on odoo
I m using Odoo 17 and this "Error new create a new record --AttributeError: '_unknown' object has no attribute 'id'-- how to solve it on Odoo" error comes when I change the type of fields in Odoo
I have changed some types of fields and now I'm getting this error.
I tried to solve it in Odoo 17 but did not get a solution

The problem occurred when I changed the type of some fields like
buyer = fields.Many2one('res.partner', copy=False)

To:
buyer = fields.Many2one('res.user', copy=False)

but I made a syntax mistake it should be res.users not res.user
so always pay attention to syntax
